# New multidimensional array assigning values from array to indices of second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

While I don't feel this is overly complex, I'm struggling with how to even search for similar questions/answers.

I have two arrays.

indices_array: `[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]`

value_array:   `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

I want to create a new array using the first array as indices for assignment and the second array for values. This should result in a new array with two values per index, however, one value being zero and the other being the value from my second array.

Using my example arrays above, it should result in:

```
[[1, 0],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 3],
 [4, 0],
 [5, 0],
 [0, 6],
 [7, 0]]
```

I can easily create an empty version of my desired array using: `np.zeros((total_len, values_per_index))`

My intuition fails when attempting something like: `target_array[indices_array] = value_array`

I believe I understand why my attempted method fails, but how to actually accomplish this eludes me. Is there a simple way of doing this? Python is not my best language by far and some of the numpy tricks seem overly magical in nature at times..

Edit: I know a for loop would accomplish this, but I'm truly looking to understand numpy better and to ideally avoid iteration when possible for code cleanliness as much as readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np

indices = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

result = np.zeros((len(indices), 2))

result[np.arange(len(indices)), indices] = values

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 2.]
 [0. 3.]
 [4. 0.]
 [5. 0.]
 [0. 6.]
 [7. 0.]]
```

See [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in numpy.

Comment: Noting my newbishness, this seems to me to be the most obvious, straight forward, and flexible implementation. It'd be easy to change the indices to be 0-3 and bump up the second shape value in the tuple for zeros, correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiplication like below

```py
indices_array = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
value_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])


## you can simply do this
value_array = np.c_[value_array * (indices_array==0), value_array * (indices_array==1)]
display(value_array)
```

Comment: upvoted on `np.c_`. I have used `np.column_stack` and `np.r_` frequently, but never know `np.c_` :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                     

a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])                                                                                                                                                    
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])                                                                                                                                                    

print(np.array([a*b,(1-a)*b]))
```

> [[0 2 3 0 0 6 0]
>
> [1 0 0 4 5 0 7]]

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use `column_stack` and multiply using numpy broadcast

```
i_arr = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
v_arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

np.column_stack((1-i_arr, i_arr)) * v_arr[:,None]

Out[61]:
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [0, 6],
       [7, 0]])
```